# Telegram KeyboardButtons not rendering UTF-8

Tags: telegram

The KeyBoardButtons don't render UTF-8 text. In other words, accented characters in Spanish (á,í,ó, etc) or Cyrillic will not render correctly. Instead, this: `Sí \xE2\x9C\x85` renders as:
[image]

In the message text itself, which is sent by the bot, accents and Cyrillic text load fine.

This happens both on both the iOS and MacOS versions of the Telegram app.

Headers are posted using cURL:
`$headers = array("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

If the messages are sending in UTF-8 correctly, why wouldn't the keyboard buttons? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code please, I think this is not API problem

Comment: Hey @Sean, thanks, I got it figured out. It was an issue with my arrays. Thank you!